# Does number of columns affect MYSQL speed?

Tags: mysql

I have a table.  I only need to run one type of query: to find a given unique in column 1, then get say, the first 3 columns out.

now, how much would it affect speed if I added an extra few columns to the table for basically "data storage".  I know I should use a saparate table, but lets assume I am constrained to having just 1 table, so the only way is to add on some columns at the end.

So, if I add on some columns, say 10 at the end, 30 varchar each, will this slow down any query given in the first sentence?  If so, by how much of a factor do you think compared to without the extra reduntant yet present columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, extra data can slow down queries because it means fewer rows can fit into a page, and this means more disk accesses to read a certain number of rows and fewer rows can be cached in memory.

The exact factor in slow down is hard to predict. It could be negligible, but if you are near the boundary between being able to cache the entire table in memory or not, a few extra columns could make a big difference to the execution speed. The difference in the time it takes to fetch a row from a cache in memory or from disk is several orders of magnitude.

If you add a [covering index](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html) the extra columns should have less of an impact as the query can use the relatively narrow index without needing to refer to the wider main table.

Comment: Hi, Regarding you answer and this from the original: I only need to run one type of query: to find a given unique value in column 1 (primary key column), then get say, the first 3 columns out.  Since column 1 is the primary unique key in my table, would this mean that MYSQL only caches 1 row, and hence the only slowdown will be caused by having to read in the extra parts of that 1 row only? or is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the 'I know I should use a separate table' bit.  What you've described is the reason you have a DB, to associate a key with some related data.  Look at it another way, how else do you retrieve this information if you don't have the key?

To answer your question, the only way to know what the performance hit is going to be is empirical testing (though Mark's answer, posted just prior to mine, is one - of VERY many - factors to speed).

Comment: Testing requires a serious amount of time to create a test database (1 day AT LEAST) then processing it...so I just hoped someone could guestimate...

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on how much data you already have in the records. The difference would normally be somewhere between almost none at all to not so big.

The difference comes from how much more data has to be loaded from disk to get to the data. The extra columns will likely mean that there is room for less records in each page, but it's possible that it happens to be room enough left in each page for most of the extra data so that there are few extra blocks needed. It depends on how well the current data lines up in the pages.